# Add buttons dynamically to ScrollView android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

So I want to add x amount of buttons to a layout in android (where x is usually between 4 and 24), and I can achieve this using the code below, but it doesn't scroll so it cuts off some of the buttons

I am using a fragment, which contains a `LinearLayout` and `BottomNavigation`, and one of those navigation options leads to the fragment contained below

At the moment my.xml file looks like:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/units_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And my code:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_course_units, container, false);

    final LinearLayout unitsBtns = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.units_group);

    //I actually get this from a volley request but didn't want to include all the code
    String[] units = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"}; 

    for(int i = 0; i < units.length; i++){
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );

        params.setMargins(0, 30, 0, 0);
        Button b = new Button(getActivity());

        b.setLayoutParams(params);
        b.setText(units[i]);
        b.setId(i);
        b.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    // STUFF HERE
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        unitsBtns.addView(b);
    }

    return view;
}
```

Is there any way to get the buttons to be scrollable? I have tried to put the `scrollView` around the parent of this too and it still doesn't seem to work.

Note: I am still pretty new to developing native Android apps so please correct me if I'm doing something incorrectly

Comment: Use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`

Comment: See my post it will help you..

Comment: I dont know if this is going to help, but you can use a listView or recyclerview containing buttons. Both are scrollable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you have to use `ScrollView` you should give android:layout_height="wrap_content" in child view of `ScrollView` then only you have to scroll your view

You should use user `LinearLayout` like this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/units_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
```

here also you have to replace

```
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

**Note: when you give `match_parent` in height attribute, it will limit your view to device screen**

hope it will help you.. :)

Comment: Thanks for this! Turned out it was a mix of this and me forgetting the offset from the BottomNavigationView so it was hiding some of the bottom buttons

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example (horizontal) :

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hsv1"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:background="#0d47a1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hsvLayout1"
            android:background="#0d47a1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Get ScrollView and Layout:

```
HorizontalScrollView hsv1 = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById( R.id.hsv1 );
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) hsv1.findViewById( R.id.hsvLayout1 );
layout.removeAllViews();
```

Create a button dynamically:

```
Button myButton = new Button (this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT );
lp.setMargins( 20, 0, 20, 0 );
myButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
myButton.setTextColor( Color.YELLOW );
myButton.setGravity( Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL );
myButton.setText( "Hello World !" );
```

Add button to layout:

```
layout.addView(myButton);
```